# Laravel Gate Issue

Tags: php, laravel, security, authorization

I'm trying to check if a user is allowed to view a page using Gates and Policies in Laravel. In my **web.php**, I have within a route:

```
$litter = Litter::find($id);

//Security gate
if(Gate::allows('edit-litter', Auth::user(), $litter)){
  return View::make('mykennel.litters.pupsheet')->with([
    //some variables
  ]);
}else{
  $ip_info = log_user_connection('Authorization Error');
  return View::make('errors.authorization')->with([
    'ip_info' => $ip_info,
    'litter_id' => $litter->id,
    'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
    'litter_user' => $litter->user_id
  ]);
}
```

My policy is like such (**AuthServiceProvider.php**):

```
public function boot()
  {
      $this->registerPolicies();

      Gate::define('edit-litter', function ($user, $litter) {
          return $user->id == $litter->user_id;
      });
  }
```

When I test this, I'm only ever getting the auth error, so I decided to check if I'm not seeing something by sending those variables above to the error view, and sure enough, the user_id equals litter_user (the two things I'm comparing):

```
{$litter_user}}, {{$user_id}} //returns '55, 55'
```

Am I missing something obvious? Any help appreciated.

Comment: you do not pass the user to the gate ... you only pass the resource, the gate knows what the authenticated user is already  `Gate::allows('ability', $resourceToCheck)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Looks like you are checking ability in wrong way**

`allows()` function requires two params first is ability and second is array of arguments

```
public function allows($ability, $arguments = [])
{
    return $this->check($ability, $arguments);
}
```

But you are calling it as:

```
Gate::allows('edit-litter', Auth::user(), $litter)
```

That can be the reason of your code not working

So change it to:

```
Gate::allows('edit-litter', $litter)
```

and try again because laravel will automatically check it for authenticated user.

Comment: glad to hear it helped :)